# How to link an Android Qt app that uses the poco libraries

Tags: poco-libraries

In order to use the poco libraries in an Qt - Android app I have compiled the libraries in this sequence:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/Android/jdk1.8.0_231
/opt/Android/android-sdk-linux/ndk/21.3.6528147/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-29 --install-dir=toolchain
export PATH=$PATH:/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/toolchain/bin/

./configure --config=Android --no-tests --no-samples --minimal
make -s -j4 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
```

In my .pro file I have included all the .a libraries so:

```
LIBS += -L/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a -lPocoEncodings
LIBS += -L/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a -lPocoFoundation
LIBS += -L/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a -lPocoJSON
LIBS += -L/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a -lPocoNet
LIBS += -L/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a -lPocoUtil
LIBS += -L/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a -lPocoXML
```

When I try to build my app I obtain this link error:

```
/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a/libPocoXML.a(xmlparse.o):xmlparse.cpp:function startParsing(XML_ParserStruct*): error: undefined reference to 'Poco::BinaryReader::operator>>(unsigned long&)'
/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a/libPocoXML.a(xmlparse.o):xmlparse.cpp:function startParsing(XML_ParserStruct*): error: undefined reference to 'Poco::BinaryReader::~BinaryReader()'
/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a/libPocoXML.a(xmlparse.o):xmlparse.cpp:function startParsing(XML_ParserStruct*): error: undefined reference to 'Poco::RandomInputStream::~RandomInputStream()'
/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a/libPocoXML.a(xmlparse.o):xmlparse.cpp:function startParsing(XML_ParserStruct*): error: undefined reference to 'Poco::BinaryReader::~BinaryReader()'
/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a/libPocoXML.a(xmlparse.o):xmlparse.cpp:function startParsing(XML_ParserStruct*): error: undefined reference to 'Poco::RandomInputStream::~RandomInputStream()'
/home/denis/Scaricati/poco-1.10.1/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a/libPocoXML.a(xmlparse.o):xmlparse.cpp:function startParsing(XML_ParserStruct*): error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone help me? Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using static libraries check that you list them in the correct order.